# Can this query be optimized to increase speed of website?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have query that's slowing down an area of my Wordpress website. I'm fairly new to sql statements and this particular statement was created by another developer. Is there a way to optimize the following statement? I'm at a loss! I have included the execution plan & table designs below but would be happy to provide any additional info. I appreciate any help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN (

    SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta

            WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location')

            AND post_id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT tr.object_id FROM wp_termmeta

                INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt on wp_termmeta.term_id = tt.term_id

                INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr on tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id

                WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND meta_key='_wc_restrictions_location')

        UNION ALL

    SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta

            WHERE (meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location' AND meta_value = 'public') OR (meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_locations' AND meta_value IN (''))

        UNION ALL

    SELECT tr.object_id FROM wp_termmeta

            INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt on wp_termmeta.term_id = tt.term_id

            INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr on tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id

            WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'

            AND ( (meta_key='_wc_restrictions_location' AND meta_value='public') OR (meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_locations' AND meta_value IN ('')) )

            AND tr.object_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location')

) as rfilter on wp_posts.ID = rfilter.post_id WHERE post_type = 'product' AND ID IN (34913,6926,6928,6929,6931,6932,6933,6934,6935,6936,6937,6938,6942,6943,6944,6945,6946,6947,6948,6949,6950,6951,6952,6953,6954,6955,6921,6956,6957,6958,6959,6960,6961,6962,6963,6964,6965,6970,6971,6973,6974,6976,6977,6979,6981,6984,6985,6986,6987,6988,6989,6990,6992,6993,6995,6996,6997,6999,7000,7001,7003,7005,7006,7008,7009,7010,7011,7012,7013,7014,7015,7016,7017,7018,7019,7020,7021,7023,7024,7025,7061,7062,7064,7065,7066,7068,7069,7070,7071,7072,7073,7074,7075,7076,7077,7078,7079,7080,7083,7084,7085,7087,7089,7090,7091,7092,7093,7094,7095,7096,7098,7099,7100,7101,7102,7103,7105,7106,7107,7108,7109,7111,7112,7113,7116,7128,7129,7130,7131,7136,7137,7338,7451,7633,7117,7348,7399,7400,7489,7540,7631,24265,24576,34966,35025,35092,35209,35287,35344,35371,35400,35414,35468,35490,35543,35598,35706,35718,35757,35838,35890,35944,36001,36039,36093,36117,36171,36183,36192,38458,39593,39667,39693,39703,39777,39783,39789,42683,44209,44693,45536,45972,46360,46749,48415,48553,48703,48715,48861,49619,49766,51010,51792,52182,53167,53171,53189,53197,53211,53230,53470,53472,53476,53478,53480,53485,53487,53489,53492,53500,53503,53505,53508,53511,53514,53517,53520,53522,53526,53529,53532,53539,53542,53544,53546,53549,53552,53555,53557,53560,53563,53566,53569,53571,53586,53613,53622,53626,53630,53633,53636,53640,53643,53647,53650,53653,53657,53660,53664,53670,53673,53676,53679,53707,53722,53739,53743,53746,53749,53774,53779,53791,53794,53797,53801,53804,53868,53887,53892,53897,53900,53908,53913,53918,53923,54279,54282,54286,54289,54292,54295,54312,54340,54347,54352,54435,54438,54441,54444,54471,54476,54594,54609,54612,54616,54619,54622,7135,35314,53494,53617);
```

EXPLAIN SELECT Results:
[image]

Describe Table Results:

```
wp_posts    CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci  

wp_postmeta CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci  

wp_termmeta CREATE TABLE `wp_termmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `term_id` (`term_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci  

wp_term_taxonomy    CREATE TABLE `wp_term_taxonomy` (
  `term_taxonomy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taxonomy` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`term_taxonomy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci  


wp_term_relationships   CREATE TABLE `wp_term_relationships` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
  KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: to answer that we need you to show us the tables design and the execution plan

Comment: Hi @GuidoG, the website is built with the Wordpress CMS and has the standard tables associated. I'm not exactly sure what its intention is unfortunately. Can you shed any light on this query for me?

Comment: As @GuidoG pointed out, we need the execution plan at the very least. To give you an idea why, it will tell us things like if the plan is using a scan instead of a seek on a particular table. It also gives us an idea what indexes (if any) are being used.

Comment: i am sorry but i do not have any wordpress here.

Comment: @dsmeclipse Please forgive me for my lack of knowledge. What do you mean by an execution plan? Are you referring to what the query is suppose to do or the setup of the database tables?

Comment: An execution plan is basically the "map" of how the database is going to search for your data. It will show how indexes are being used, time spent on each part of the query, etc.

Here's a deeper explanation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan

Comment: @Christy Change `SELECT` to `EXPLAIN SELECT` at the start of your query, run it, and copy paste the results into your question. Likewise, you can `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_posts` to provide the table design. Repeat for each table used in the query.

Comment: @WillemRenzema  I added the results to the original questions. Please let me know if you need any additional info. Thank you so much for the info!

Comment: @dsmeclipse Thank you for the link! I believe I have added the requested execution plan to the original image. Let me know if you need any additional info. Thanks again.

Comment: @RickJames and I have collaborated on a [WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)  to put better indexes on `wp_postmeta` and a few other WordPress tables.  It may help performance in cases like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for these two changes to optimize this query:

1. Add proper indexes.
2. The OR conditions prevent proper use of indexes. Therefore, I would split the condition to two parts (duplicate the relevant query part) and combine it with a UNION DISTINCT. If you don't care about duplicates, replace the UNION DISTINCT to UNION ALL.
3. There are 3 places where you have a join ON clause similar to: 
   *tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id*
   The problem here is that these two columns are of different types (one is int(11) and the other is bigint(20)). The difference in types will prevent proper index use. Therefore, if possible, I would consider changing the column types to match.

Let's start with adding the indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` ADD INDEX `wp_postmeta_index_1` (`meta_key`, `meta_value`, `post_id`);
ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` ADD INDEX `wp_postmeta_index_2` (`meta_key`, `post_id`); 
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD INDEX `wp_posts_index_1` (`post_type`, `ID`); 
ALTER TABLE `wp_term_relationships` ADD INDEX `wp_term_relationships_index_1` (`term_taxonomy_id`, `object_id`); 
ALTER TABLE `wp_term_taxonomy` ADD INDEX `wp_term_taxonomy_index_1` (`taxonomy`, `term_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`); 
ALTER TABLE `wp_termmeta` ADD INDEX `wp_termmeta_index_1` (`meta_key`, `meta_value`, `term_id`); 
ALTER TABLE `wp_termmeta` ADD INDEX `wp_termmeta_index_2` (`meta_key`, `term_id`);
```

So let's look at the optimized query:

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT wp_posts.ID 
    FROM
        wp_posts 
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                wp_postmeta.post_id 
            FROM
                wp_postmeta 
            WHERE
                wp_postmeta.post_id NOT IN (
                    SELECT
                        wp_postmeta.post_id 
                    FROM
                        wp_postmeta 
                    WHERE
                        wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location'
                ) 
                AND wp_postmeta.post_id NOT IN (
                    SELECT
                        DISTINCT tr.object_id 
                    FROM
                        wp_termmeta 
                    INNER JOIN
                        wp_term_taxonomy tt 
                            ON wp_termmeta.term_id = tt.term_id 
                    INNER JOIN
                        wp_term_relationships tr 
                            ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
                    WHERE
                        tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' 
                        AND wp_termmeta.meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location'
                ) 
            UNION
            ALL SELECT
                wp_postmeta.post_id 
            FROM
                wp_postmeta 
            WHERE
                (
                    wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location' 
                    AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'public'
                ) 
            UNION
            ALL SELECT
                tr.object_id 
            FROM
                wp_termmeta 
            INNER JOIN
                wp_term_taxonomy tt 
                    ON wp_termmeta.term_id = tt.term_id 
            INNER JOIN
                wp_term_relationships tr 
                    ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
            WHERE
                tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' 
                AND (
                    (
                        wp_termmeta.meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location' 
                        AND wp_termmeta.meta_value = 'public'
                    )
                ) 
                AND tr.object_id NOT IN (
                    SELECT
                        DISTINCT wp_postmeta.post_id 
                    FROM
                        wp_postmeta 
                    WHERE
                        wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location'
                ) 
            UNION
            DISTINCT SELECT
                wp_postmeta.post_id 
            FROM
                wp_postmeta 
            WHERE
                (
                    wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_locations' 
                    AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN (
                        ''
                    )
                ) 
            UNION
            DISTINCT SELECT
                tr.object_id 
            FROM
                wp_termmeta 
            INNER JOIN
                wp_term_taxonomy tt 
                    ON wp_termmeta.term_id = tt.term_id 
            INNER JOIN
                wp_term_relationships tr 
                    ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
            WHERE
                tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' 
                AND (
                    (
                        wp_termmeta.meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_locations' 
                        AND wp_termmeta.meta_value IN (
                            ''
                        )
                    )
                ) 
                AND tr.object_id NOT IN (
                    SELECT
                        DISTINCT wp_postmeta.post_id 
                    FROM
                        wp_postmeta 
                    WHERE
                        wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wc_restrictions_location'
                )
            ) AS rfilter 
                ON wp_posts.ID = rfilter.post_id 
        WHERE
            wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
            AND wp_posts.ID IN (
                34913, 6926, 6928, 6929, 6931, 6932, 6933, 6934, 6935, 6936, 6937, 6938, 6942, 6943, 6944, 6945, 6946, 6947, 6948, 6949, 6950, 6951, 6952, 6953, 6954, 6955, 6921, 6956, 6957, 6958, 6959, 6960, 6961, 6962, 6963, 6964, 6965, 6970, 6971, 6973, 6974, 6976, 6977, 6979, 6981, 6984, 6985, 6986, 6987, 6988, 6989, 6990, 6992, 6993, 6995, 6996, 6997, 6999, 7000, 7001, 7003, 7005, 7006, 7008, 7009, 7010, 7011, 7012, 7013, 7014, 7015, 7016, 7017, 7018, 7019, 7020, 7021, 7023, 7024, 7025, 7061, 7062, 7064, 7065, 7066, 7068, 7069, 7070, 7071, 7072, 7073, 7074, 7075, 7076, 7077, 7078, 7079, 7080, 7083, 7084, 7085, 7087, 7089, 7090, 7091, 7092, 7093, 7094, 7095, 7096, 7098, 7099, 7100, 7101, 7102, 7103, 7105, 7106, 7107, 7108, 7109, 7111, 7112, 7113, 7116, 7128, 7129, 7130, 7131, 7136, 7137, 7338, 7451, 7633, 7117, 7348, 7399, 7400, 7489, 7540, 7631, 24265, 24576, 34966, 35025, 35092, 35209, 35287, 35344, 35371, 35400, 35414, 35468, 35490, 35543, 35598, 35706, 35718, 35757, 35838, 35890, 35944, 36001, 36039, 36093, 36117, 36171, 36183, 36192, 38458, 39593, 39667, 39693, 39703, 39777, 39783, 39789, 42683, 44209, 44693, 45536, 45972, 46360, 46749, 48415, 48553, 48703, 48715, 48861, 49619, 49766, 51010, 51792, 52182, 53167, 53171, 53189, 53197, 53211, 53230, 53470, 53472, 53476, 53478, 53480, 53485, 53487, 53489, 53492, 53500, 53503, 53505, 53508, 53511, 53514, 53517, 53520, 53522, 53526, 53529, 53532, 53539, 53542, 53544, 53546, 53549, 53552, 53555, 53557, 53560, 53563, 53566, 53569, 53571, 53586, 53613, 53622, 53626, 53630, 53633, 53636, 53640, 53643, 53647, 53650, 53653, 53657, 53660, 53664, 53670, 53673, 53676, 53679, 53707, 53722, 53739, 53743, 53746, 53749, 53774, 53779, 53791, 53794, 53797, 53801, 53804, 53868, 53887, 53892, 53897, 53900, 53908, 53913, 53918, 53923, 54279, 54282, 54286, 54289, 54292, 54295, 54312, 54340, 54347, 54352, 54435, 54438, 54441, 54444, 54471, 54476, 54594, 54609, 54612, 54616, 54619, 54622, 7135, 35314, 53494, 53617
            )
```

Comment: Thank you @Tomer. I was having the hardest time with this. I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

- Use `LEFT JOIN  ... IS NULL` instead of `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`
- Follow my [*tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) on the indexing of `wp_postmeta`.  (Based on those huge numbers in `EXPLAIN`, this may help a lot.)

(If you still have performance problems, present the new versions of the queries and schema for further critique.)

Some details...

In the past, `IN ( SELECT ... )` was reevaluated for every possible outer rows.  This was terribly inefficient.  Newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB either do the inner `SELECT` once, but then construct an index (not free), or turn it into a `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ... (slightly modified) ... )`; this is reasonably competitive with `LEFT JOIN`.

This forum is littered with examples of `IN (...)` and (less often) `NOT IN (...)`.  The `NOT IN` construct is probably a lot worse than the `IN`.

(Sorry, I don't have a reference, just years of experience.)

Comment: Is there any documentation for the fact that LEFT JOIN is preferred in terms of performance over NOT IN? Can you please elaborate why would this change improve performance? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the details. Do you know of any cases from your experience where this alternative will backfire (has disadvantage)? I'm trying to ask in which cases choosing LEFT JOIN in my query will stop working better than NOT IN (for example, when data grows, when query changes, etc.)?

Comment: @TomShir - I can't think of a case with `IN`.  Some other subqueries have a difference like that -- such as when the subquery shrinks the number of rows via `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT`.  Those don't apply to `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  In my experience, `IN ( SELECT ... )` is never _faster_ than a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to elaborate! :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Rick, where in or not in clauses should be avoided and replaced by exists or not exists.

```
select col1, col2, col3
from tab1 t1
where exists (select 1 from tab2 where col1 = t1.col1)
```